# neo4j cypher query very slow using nested brackets

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

When querying neo4j using cypher ive tried 2 queries

Slow query

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ CYPHER 1.9 START entity=node:`PimDomainIndex_HFDgOXRJjq.nl_ed1`("*:*") WHERE (((((has(entity.str) and entity.str=~'(?i).*Q1E.*') and  (has(entity.`1_to_3`) and entity.`1_to_3`=1)) and  (has(entity.nr) and entity.nr=1)) and  (has(entity.`1_to_2`) and entity.`1_to_2`=~'(?i).*Q1E.*')) and  (has(entity.b) and entity.b="true")) and  (has(entity.nr) and entity.date<=1427666400000) RETURN count(DISTINCT entity);
==> +------------------------+
==> | count(DISTINCT entity) |
==> +------------------------+
==> | 0                      |
==> +------------------------+
==> 1 row
==> 
==> 328954 ms
```

profile:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE498258e2-ee6d-4959-8259-4fa1fad3eb11"], returnItemNames=["count(DISTINCT entity)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==> EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE498258e2-ee6d-4959-8259-4fa1fad3eb11,Distinct)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>   Filter(pred="(((((((((((hasProp(str) AND LiteralRegularExpression) AND hasProp(1_to_3)) AND Property == Literal) AND hasProp(nr)) AND Property == Literal) AND hasProp(1_to_2)) AND LiteralRegularExpression) AND hasProp(b)) AND Property == Literal) AND hasProp(nr)) AND Property <= Literal)", _rows=0, _db_hits=6)
==>     Nodes(name="entity", _rows=3, _db_hits=3)
==>       ParameterPipe(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
```

Fast query

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ CYPHER 1.9 START entity=node:`DomainIndex_HFDgOXRJjq.nl_ed1`("*:*")  WITH entity  WHERE (has(entity.str) and entity.str=~'(?i).*Q1E.*') and  (has(entity.`1_to_3`) and entity.`1_to_3`=1) and  (has(entity.nr) and entity.nr=1) and  (has(entity.`1_to_2`) and entity.`1_to_2`=~'(?i).*Q1E.*') and  (has(entity.b) and entity.b="true") and  (has(entity.nr) and entity.date<=1427666400000) WITH entity RETURN count(DISTINCT entity);
==> +------------------------+
==> | count(DISTINCT entity) |
==> +------------------------+
==> | 0                      |
==> +------------------------+
==> 1 row
==> 
==> 1786 ms
```

Profile

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE54528d13-254e-4914-b260-26b9f09fcc36"], returnItemNames=["count(DISTINCT entity)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==> EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE54528d13-254e-4914-b260-26b9f09fcc36,Distinct)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
==>   Filter(pred="(((((((((((hasProp(str) AND LiteralRegularExpression) AND hasProp(1_to_3)) AND Property == Literal) AND hasProp(nr)) AND Property == Literal) AND hasProp(1_to_2)) AND LiteralRegularExpression) AND hasProp(b)) AND Property == Literal) AND hasProp(nr)) AND Property <= Literal)", _rows=0, _db_hits=6)
==>     Nodes(name="entity", _rows=3, _db_hits=3)
==>       ParameterPipe(_rows=1, _db_hits=0)
```

The only difference between the two queries is the usage of the "(",")" brackets,
The brackets are required for future business logic but the performance is a major issue.

The index contains ~3 nodes and test database contains only ~15 nodes.

```
==> | Node[13]{nr:2.0,date:1393459200000,str:"2"}         |
==> | Node[14]{b:false,nr:3.0,date:1393804800000,str:"3"} |
==> | Node[15]{b:true,nr:1.0,date:1392163200000,str:"1"}  |
```

What is the reason for the major performance decrease when using brackets and how can this be solved?

Comment: I think this might be a historical problem in this older version of Neo4j (you're using "CYPHER 1.9", which forces use of the older compiler). Perhaps try it in Neo4j 2.0?

Comment: The neo4j version that was used is 1.9.5, I can't switch to neo4j 2 at the moment. Ive tried upgrading to 1.9.6 but the problem persists.